# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_tex

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

When I execute the code, I get an error that says

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text'

```
from selenium import webdriver

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

data = web.find_element_by_link_text("View source")
data.click()
```

Comment: because there is more than one element with <View source> on the page